# How to reference ctor overload documentation with <inheritdoc/>?

Tags: c#

How to reference ctor overload documentation with ?

```
        /// <param name="serviceProvider">Loads <see cref="ApplicationDbContext"/>, <see cref="IUserSessionService"/> and <see cref="AuditSettings"/></param>
        protected ConventionDbContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;

        /// <inheritdoc <see cref="ConventionDbContext.???"/> (nothing like .ctor...)
        /// <param name="options">Options</param>
        protected ConventionDbContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, [NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
            => ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `<inheritdoc cref="ConventionDbContext(IServiceProvider)" />`. In my tests VS will still issue a warning for missing docs on the first parameter, although the doc does appear copied from the other constructor.

Comment: this works and I also get the warning. What exactly will be copied? Everything? What with duplicte definitions? Who's gonns win?